# Is the converse of the sequence lemma false in general？

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I think the converse of the sequence lemma cannot hold without the property of being first countable, but I couldn't find any counterexamples.

The sequence lemma:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, $A⊆X$ any subset and $x∈X$. If there is a sequence of points in $A$ converging to $x$, then $x∈\text{cl}(A)$; the converse holds if $X$ is first-countable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The spaces in which the converse of this lemma holds are called [Frechet-Urysohn spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space), or sometimes they are just called Frechet spaces.

Comment: You can find [three different examples](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Fr%C3%A9chet%20Urysohn%20%2B%20not%20First%20Countable) of such spaces which aren't first countable on pi-base, as well as plenty of examples of [spaces which aren't Frechet-Urysohn](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=not%20Fr%C3%A9chet%20Urysohn)

Comment: Let $(X, \tau) $ be a cocountable space where $X$ is uncountable. 

Choose a proper uncountable subset $A$ of $X$.